# MariaDB error message error when connecting to a database: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, database, pdo, mariadb

I am doing a project where I have a registration form that I am trying to send to a MariaDB database to store the registration form values. I have an example from my professor and I have copied it for the most part, just changing some of the values I need to bind. The two following files are connected through a php file, that I don't think is necessary to see. However when the user submits the correct input I run into an error message(line 4 is marked below):

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

I attached an image of my webpage after submitting and getting an error.
This first "connectionInfo.php" file contains variable for the database name and password:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $dbname = "project";
    $dbuserName = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
?>
```

this next file, "insertValidData.php" contains the main code to access and send information to the database:

```
<?php
    if($isValid){
        try{
            $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbname", $dbuserName, $dbpassword);// line 4

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (userName, password, firstName, lastName, address1, address2, city, state, zipCode, phone, email, gender, maritalStatus, dateOfBirth)
             VALUES (:userName, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zipCode,:phone, :email, :gender, :maritalStatus, :dateOfBirth");


            $sql->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
            $sql->bindParam(':password', $password);
            $sql->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
            $sql->bindParam(':lastName', $lastName);
            $sql->bindParam(':address1', $address);
            $sql->bindParam(':address2', $address2);
            $sql->bindParam(':city', $city);
            $sql->bindParam(':state', $state);
            $sql->bindParam(':zipCode', $zipcode);
            $sql->bindParam(':phone', $phoneNumber);
            $sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $sql->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
            $sql->bindParam(':maritalStatus', $maritalStat);
            $sql->bindParam(':dateOfBirth', $birthday);
            
            $sql->execute();

            $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
            $_SESSION["last_id"] = "last_id";

            header("Location: confirmation.php");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection Falied: " . $e->getMessage();
            
        } finally{
            $conn = null;
        }
    }


?>
```

pic of the MariaDB database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hph09.png)

I have also check to make sure that the variables in connectionInfo.php are the same as in insertValidData.php and if I echo them out it seems that they are. I am really not sure what to do, I have even asked my teacher and they said it looks fine so I thought I would try asking here.

Comment: It's fine what you all explain about your code, however what I think would be more interesting in context of the error message you were able to summon with it is: What did your syntax check with the MariaDB manual revealed?

Comment: The error message refers to line 4. But SQL code in shown PHP code does not contains so much lines. *line 4 is marked below* You mark PHP line which MariaDB cannot tell about.

Comment: Are you sure that the script which you posted is executed?  Executing this script should result in a PHP parser error, not in a MySQL/MariaDB error. Also there is no SQL statement in this script which has 4 or more lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be something minor. You may have forgotten to add parentheses. Wrong use

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (userName, password, firstName, lastName, address1, address2, city, state, zipCode, phone, email, gender, maritalStatus, dateOfBirth)
             VALUES (:userName, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zipCode,:phone, :email, :gender, :maritalStatus, :dateOfBirth");
```

Would you try this?

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (userName, password, firstName, lastName, address1, address2, city, state, zipCode, phone, email, gender, maritalStatus, dateOfBirth)
        VALUES (:userName, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zipCode,:phone, :email, :gender, :maritalStatus, :dateOfBirth)");
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work. Thanks a lot. I was staring at this thing for about an hour and a half and didn't notice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thank you. Could you please mark it as solved? I'll have some reputation. :) @Mateo John

Comment: @0x4nt Forgotten parentheses will result in a PHP parse error, not in a MariaDB server error.